# Is there any way to force the update of drivers for an Nvidia GeForce GT 230M on a Sony Vaio laptop?

Tags: sony-vaio, nvidia-geforce

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with a Nvidia GeForce GT 230M video card.

- The latest version available through Vaio Support is from 28 November 2010.
- The latest version available from Nvidia website is from 10 October 2012.

That's more than a year apart between the updates.

Tt=he problem is that when trying to update graphics driver using the installer from the Nvidia website, I get an error pop-up saying that I have to download the driver from the manufacturer website.

> “Your product manufacturer requires you to download a driver for your device from their website.”

Is there any way to get around this and force an update?

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding updated drivers on [LaptopVideo2Go](https://forums.laptopvideo2go.com), to find the `DEV` and `SUBSYS` go to your Device Manager then :

[image]

Copy these two values on the site and they **may** have updated drivers for your laptop.

**Try at your own risk** (But I've never had a problem with this method on a Fujitsu-Siemens and a an HP).